# Inserting X number of rows dependent on cell value and formatting the new rows

Tags: vba, excel

I have a table of data in Excel 2010 starting from row 10, each row containing a calculated number (X) in column I. The code is intended to insert (X) number of new rows below any row in the table when (X) is more than 1.

The current code achieves this, but as new entries are made into the table and I run the code again, more blank rows are added below the additional rows already inserted.

I'd also like to copy the information in columns A:G from the row containing (X) to each of the newly inserted rows, and make the original row appear in bold text.

```
Sub Insert_SB()
Dim lngCounter As Long

For lngCounter = Range("I" & Rows.count).End(xlUp).row To 10 Step -1


    With Cells(lngCounter, "I")

    If IsNumeric(.Value) And .Value > 1 Then
    With .Offset(1, 0).Resize(.Value - 1, 1)
    .EntireRow.Insert
    End With
    If IsNumeric(.Value) And .Value = 0 Then Exit For

End If
End With

Next lngCounter

End Sub
```

Comment: I can't think of any specific line of code now, but concept-wise: Mark the rows you inserted with a flag or somehow check for already inserted rows before inserting any new ones.

Answer (score 0):

Your code will insert, say 5 blank rows beneath then number 5 in cell I11 for example. When you run the code again, it will again find the number 5 and insert another 5 rows.... You will need to tell it that it doesn't need to. That is to say you will need to either count the blank rows beneath the number 5 first, to see if there are already 5, or you need to mark the 5 as "done" (maybe by writing to column K perhaps)

This function could potentially tell you if you need to add rows:

```
Function NeedsMoreRows(rngToCheck As Range) As Boolean
Dim intNumBlankRows As Integer
Dim intCounter As Integer

    'this is the number of blank rows it should have underneath it
    intNumBlankRows = rngToCheck.Value

    For intCounter = 1 To intNumBlankRows

        If ActiveSheet.Cells(rngToCheck.Row + intCounter, rngToCheck.Column) <> vbNullString Then NeedsMoreRows = True


    Next intCounter



End Function
```

If IsNumeric(.Value) And .Value > 1 And NeedsMoreRows(Cells(lngCounter, "A")) Then

Comment: Thank you for responding so quickly Alex and James. Is there any way to count the X blank rows within the code to ensure it doesn't insert again?

Comment: something like the function I have put above. You could expand it to insert intcounter - intnumblankrows if you wanted to as well

Comment: Just trying to figure out how and where to use the function you provided- I'm very new to Excel. I've placed the function into a module, added a new column to the table and put =NeedMoreRows(I10:I300). I'm obviously using it incorrectly as #VALUE error comes up.

Comment: I added something above, which is how I think you would call it